# How to get element with a certain attribute and without another with vanilla js?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get an element that has an attribute of `title="some title"` but there are multiple ones that come back and I'm to get the first one that has no style attribute.

I tried adding the `:not[style]` to my select it as an additional argument but it did not work.

```
document.querySelector(':not([style])', 'not[title="Add to Bag"]');
```

the element I'm looking for should be:

```
<button type="submit" class="pdp-add-to-bag add-to-cart pid-19GRB-004f78165ba0cb247a9d38d110" title="Add to Bag">Add to Bag</button>
```

Comment: Why do you use `not[title...]` when actually looking for the element with that title?

Comment: You're looking for an element that matches both selectors: `:not[style][title="Add to Bag"]`. Although I echo @raina77ow's question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combine the two selectors - `'[title="Add to Bag"]:not([style])'`:

```js
const els = document.querySelectorAll('[title="Add to Bag"]:not([style])');

console.log('Number of buttons found: ', els.length);

console.log(els[0]);
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="pdp-add-to-bag add-to-cart pid-19GRB-004f78165ba0cb247a9d38d110" title="Add to Bag">Add to Bag</button>

<button type="submit" class="pdp-add-to-bag add-to-cart pid-19GRB-004f78165ba0cb247a9d38d110" title="Add to Bag" style="color: red;">Add to Bag</button>
```

Comment: I wonder isn't it it better performance-wise to use two querySelector lookups here - first for title only, second for :not(style). But that shouldn't be a concern anyway. )

Comment: I'm using querySelectorAll to demonstrate that it finds the 1st button, but ignores the 2nd due to style. He should use `querySelector` to find a single item.